Не отображаются товары из категории в вордпрессе. Плагин woocommerce
У меня проблема с сервисом woocommerce, я добавила товары и категории, а также поиск товаров. Но поиск работает у меня только в том случае, если я пишу точное название товара (например насосы он мне не найдет, а если насосы эцв 4-25-60, то перейдет сразу на страницу товара). И когда я нажимаю на категорию, отображаются все товары на сайте, а не из определенной категории. В чем может быть проблема? Я нигде не могу найти решение, а в коде я разбираюсь плохо, поэтому решила оставить свой вопрос отдельно. У меня есть плагин "YITH WooCommerce catalog mode" (потому что мне нужен просто каталог, без покупки напрямую) и плагин "YITH WooCommerce Ajax product filter" (но он отключен). До этого я пробовал еще пару плагинов, а именно "jetpack" и "Yoast SEO", но теперь они отключены.
Может ли это быть связано с воздействием "YITH WooCommerce Ajax product filter" или "Jetpack"? (они оба отключены, но возможно они как-то повлияли на базы данных или какие-то функции.) И еще один момент заключается в том, что не отображаются товары по категориям, но если я зайду на страницу товара, то в самом низу мне советуют товары из категории. То есть он может различать, какие товары относятся к какой категории, но не может отображать их на странице каталога через функцию.
Я попытался отключить все плагины, но проблема не была решена. Я очистил кэш браузера, отключил SEO-плагины и заново создал категории товаров, но опять ничего.
Я не знаю, что делать, у меня сайт почти полностью готов, и проблема только в этом. Я понимаю, что проблема просто решается, ведь он видит товары в категории, но просто не может вывести их в каталоге.

Оплатите работу WP специалиста и не занимайтесь тыканьев неизвесных строк кода непонятно куда... проблему вы так не решите.

Это, конечно, простой способ, но хотелось бы выяснить почему именно так и почему это касается только одной функции.

Этого нельзя понять по текстовому описанию просто с Ваших слов, тем более не понятно что Вы подразумеваете под "не может отображать их на странице каталога через функцию" и так далее. Тем более что плагин YITH WooCommerce Catalog Mode является премиум плагином, Вы можете обратиться напрямую к ним в поддержку или у Вас free version?

Я про то, что есть блок "Список категорий товаров", где при нажатии на категорию выводятся соответствующие товары (в начале создания сайта всё работало). Теперь оно перестал работать. То есть при нажатии на категорию отображаются все товары. Но в то же время в карточке товаров, в самом низу, где плагин советует доп. товары из этой же категории всё отображается правильно. Соответственно, проблема как будто только в блоке "список категорий товаров", ибо он не хочет выводить никак. Надеюсь, так более понятно. И "YITH WooCommerce Catalog Mode" бесплатный плагин.

И кто-то должен по текстовому описанию разгадать, что же у Вас пошло не так и что изменилось с момента создания сайта, я верно понял? У плагина есть две версии, плантная и бесплатная. Свой вопрос можете адресовать разработчикам плагина здесь

Почему здесь все такие грубые-то. Мне откуда знать, могут понять в чем проблема или нет. На других форумах почему-то стараются помочь, а не упрекнуть или осудить. Если бы я знала - не писала бы сюда, спасибо.

@LaymiMoore если считаете какие-то комментарии грубыми, Вы можете на них пожаловаться, но никакой грубости или агрессии лично я к Вам не проявлял. На Ваш вопрос нельзя дать объективный ответ, так как по текстовому описанию нельзя понять в чем конкретная проблема. Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.
